# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' error while scraping multiple urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

```
data = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for url in urls:
    page = driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    text = soup.find('h1', class_ = 'entry-title').text
    article_text=soup.find('div',  class_ ="td-post-content tagdiv-type").text

driver.close()
```

I tried to loop urls by creating list of urls and to scrap article title and article text but after going through few urls it gave me `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' error`.Then I used selenium to automate the process but it still gave me the error.Here is the link of urls
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GDjSbDVmYLCe-wdjVs-Df1FHlgc_X4ia/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Should it not be `BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)` ? Would be good idea to check your question again and improve it so that everybody could reproduce your issue easily. This also means to provide a specific url that causes the issue and not something that needs login. Thanks